# Building a form for use with paypal REST API

Tags: paypal

I am currently building a site that processes credit card payments with paypal's API.

I was wondering what best practices are involved with building the HTML form inputs that will gather the card #, first name, last name?

I was able to use one of the samples to process a credit card (sandbox).  Eventually I connected the required CC values as POST values, and now I have a basic form.

I'm a bit worried about releasing this into the wild without consulting someone about the HTML form fields - what would be the best way to ensure a user does not get their CC info stolen?

Answer (score 0):

Well first and foremost, if your collecting CC info, you're going to want to get a PCI compliance check. There are plenty of companies out there that will do a PCI Compliance scan for you.

Once you have this, you will either get an all clear or get a list of problems you have to fix (and sometimes how to fix them).

I'd start with this.

Comment: I am not collecting CC info... just charging it.  Paypal actually stores the credit card info as a unique ID for later use.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding... you ARE collecting it. you just arent SAVING it. The data is still going through your servers, which means you need to be PCI compliant.

Comment: @Sugitime : How can I redirect a user to paypal's payment form??

Comment: I would check out the Express Checkout API. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec